# How to merge two QGraphicsItems into a custom one?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a problem that I don't know how to face and I was looking for some help. I recently started using Qt and I do not really know how Qgraphicsitems works.

I have a scene and I have to create a group of graphics items everytime my program starts, but sometimes I have to update some of those items that are always together.

So I was thinking about creating one Qgraphicsitem with all of them in it. That way i can handle them easily. My problem is that I'm not sure if that is a good approach. In a modular point of view it make sense because that group of items are always toguether and that way I do not have to create all of them everytime, but I do not know how to do it in the first plane how can I create a QgraphicsItem that has some QgraphicsItems in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for QGraphicsItemGroup:

> The QGraphicsItemGroup class provides a container that treats a group of items as a single item.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it, but I think that exactly what I was looking for